# How to connect facebook send button with facebook UI?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

After loading FB UI this is my Code:

```
<div class="fb-send" data-href="https://www.gmx.de" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

Now I want to add 2 different users (prefilled in the dialog).
There is code like this:

```
 FB.ui({
    method: "send",
    link: "http://www.google.com/",
    to: ["zuck","dmp"]
  }, 
  function(response) { alert(response); }
 );
```

But how can I connect the Facebook-Button with this code?!

Comment: Why is the first html code required? You are trying to open the dialog two times? Why?

Comment: Ah is it possible to call the second code in a jQuery click event fore example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [Send Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/send-button/) and [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) both- which isnt required! Both do almost the same thing.

I think you thought that you could pre-fill the recipients using the `to` parameter - that's right BUT you cannot add more than one recipient. You can use `to` with one `user-id` only.

On click of a button / html element-  call `FB.ui` method, this will open the send dialog.